# Confetti falling animation problem transparencies

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening all,
i added the confetti falling animation to my website.
The confetti are superimposed on my buttons and i can't click them, how can i make the confetti visible but transparent so that i can click what's underneath?

This is the code that i used:

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>

<script src="assets/index.min.js"></script>
<script> var confettiSettings = { target: 'my-canvas' };
var confetti = new ConfettiGenerator(confettiSettings);
confetti.render();
</script>

<style>
#my-canvas
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100000;
    
}


</style>
```

Comment: Try to add `pointer-events: none;` to your class.

Comment: Unfortunately "pointer-events" is not recognized, idk how can do it!

Comment: Im sorry but what do you mean with "is not recognized"?

Comment: When i wrote pointer-events: none; the command "pointer-events" dont become blue, but stay white

Comment: Ah ok. This should not be a problem tho. Just add it and try if it works because `pointer-events: none;` ist definitely valid css :D

Comment: Glad I could help you with this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pointer-events` CSS property to control some aspects of how the pointer interacts with an element. Setting `pointer-events: none;` will let pointer events (like hover and click) pass right through an element as though it wasn't there. Here's some documentation: [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 1):

here I hope this helps:

index.html

```
<div class="js-container container"></div>
```

index.css

```
@keyframes confetti-slow {
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(0) rotateY(0); }
  
  100% { transform: translate3d(25px, 105vh, 0) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(180deg); }
}

@keyframes confetti-medium {
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(0) rotateY(0); }
  
  100% { transform: translate3d(100px, 105vh, 0) rotateX(100deg) rotateY(360deg); }
}

@keyframes confetti-fast {
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(0) rotateY(0); }
  
  100% { transform: translate3d(-50px, 105vh, 0) rotateX(10deg) rotateY(250deg); }
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.confetti-container {
  perspective: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.confetti {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  border-radius: 0%;

  &--animation-slow {
    animation: confetti-slow 2.25s linear 1 forwards;
  }
  
  &--animation-medium {
    animation: confetti-medium 1.75s linear 1 forwards;
  }
  
  &--animation-fast {
    animation: confetti-fast 1.25s linear 1 forwards;
  }
}
```

script file

```
const Confettiful = function(el) {
  this.el = el;
  this.containerEl = null;
  
  this.confettiFrequency = 3;
  this.confettiColors = ['#fce18a', '#ff726d', '#b48def', '#f4306d'];
  this.confettiAnimations = ['slow', 'medium', 'fast'];
  
  this._setupElements();
  this._renderConfetti();
};

Confettiful.prototype._setupElements = function() {
  const containerEl = document.createElement('div');
  const elPosition = this.el.style.position;
  
  if (elPosition !== 'relative' || elPosition !== 'absolute') {
    this.el.style.position = 'relative';
  }
  
  containerEl.classList.add('confetti-container');
  
  this.el.appendChild(containerEl);
  
  this.containerEl = containerEl;
};

Confettiful.prototype._renderConfetti = function() {
  this.confettiInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const confettiEl = document.createElement('div');
    const confettiSize = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 7) + 'px';
    const confettiBackground = this.confettiColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.confettiColors.length)];
    const confettiLeft = (Math.floor(Math.random() * this.el.offsetWidth)) + 'px';
    const confettiAnimation = this.confettiAnimations[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.confettiAnimations.length)];
    
    confettiEl.classList.add('confetti', 'confetti--animation-' + confettiAnimation);
    confettiEl.style.left = confettiLeft;
    confettiEl.style.width = confettiSize;
    confettiEl.style.height = confettiSize;
    confettiEl.style.backgroundColor = confettiBackground;
    
    confettiEl.removeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      confettiEl.parentNode.removeChild(confettiEl);
    }, 3000);
    
    this.containerEl.appendChild(confettiEl);
  }, 25);
};

window.confettiful = new Confettiful(document.querySelector('.js-container'));
```

Here is a link of a Codepen.io:  https://codepen.io/jacobgunnarsson/pen/pbPwga